# Publish website not available in Visual Studio 2010 project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am trying to publish my project named `memberlogin`, which contains many webpages. However i don't get the Publish Website option in the Build drop down menu.

What seems to have gone wrong?

I am sharing the screenshot of what i see:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in that it is showing the Publish "YourProjectName" there. "memberlogin" is your project name that will be published. Clicking on that that will show you another dialog where you can select the publish method ( Web Deploy/ file System /FTP)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You publish per project in your solution. Select the website you want to publish in the solution explorer.

The build options you see are referencing the "current project" which is active (bold) in the solution explorer